# how to define a tf.Variable with a dynamic shape

Tags: tensorflow

My input tensor is generated from a tf.data.Iterator.get_next(), which has a dynamic shape (like [-1, 10, 10]), and -1 indicates the dynamic batch size.
Now in an operation involving the input tensor, I need to define a tf.Variable which also has a dynamic shape(like[-1, 10, 10]) to match the shape of my input tensor.
But I get an error: `ValueError: Shape of a new variable (test/conv2d_1/beta) must be fully defined, but instead was (?, 100, 100, 96).`
Does anyone know how to deal with it? Appreciate it.

Comment: You could try to set `validate_shape=False` in the `tf.Variable` call to ignore the requirement of a known shape.

Comment: I doubt this is possible. The whole purpose of a variable is that it's a "persistent" tensor that stays the same over multiple training iterations (safe for changes made through assign ops). Thus it needs to have a fully defined shape. What are you trying to achieve exactly?